# Finding upper bound on x and y

Tags: upper-lower-bounds

I want to find upper bound on following i equality without calculator.
   $${x^2}{y^5} \gt {2^x}{5^y}  $$

How can I get this done?

Comment: Do you want an upper bound of x in terms of y (and vice versa), or do you want an upper bound for x that holds for all y (and vice versa)?

Comment: an upper bound for x that holds for all y

Comment: If all $y$, $y=-1$ leads false.

Comment: lower bound is x,y > 0

Answer (score 1):

It's obvious that $x\neq0$ and $y>0$.

We can rewrite our inequality in the following form.
$$\frac{x^2}{2^x}>\frac{5^y}{y^5}.$$

Easy to see that $$\left\{\frac{5^y}{y^5}|y>0\right\}=\left[\left(\frac{e\ln5}{5}\right)^5,+\infty\right)$$ and
$$\left\{\frac{x^2}{2^x}|x\neq0\right\}=\mathbb R^{+}$$

Thus, do not exist upper bound  for $y$

because for all $y>0$, where $x\neq0$ for which $\frac{x^2}{2^x}>\frac{5^y}{y^5}$ is true.

Now, let $x_0$ is a biggest root of the equation
$$\frac{x^2}{2^x}=\left(\frac{e\ln5}{5}\right)^5.$$
Since, $\max\limits_{x>0}\frac{x^2}{2^x}>\left(\frac{e\ln5}{5}\right)^5$ and $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{x^2}{2^x}=0$,

we see that for all $x<x_0$ there is $y>0$ for which $\frac{x^2}{2^x}>\frac{5^y}{y^5}$ is true.

Thus, $$\sup_{\frac{x^2}{2^x}>\frac{5^y}{y^5} is true}x=x_0=6.252...$$
Done!

Comment: how can we say that for all x > 0 there is y > 0 for which inequality is true.

Comment: @Muhammad Saboor I made a mistake. I fixed my post. See now please.

Comment: can you tell me how $$ \left\{\frac{5^y}{y^5}|y>0\right\}=\left[\left(\frac{e\ln5}{5}\right)^5,+\infty\right) $$

Comment: @Muhammad Saboor Because $\lim\limits_{y\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{5^y}{y^5}=+\infty$. $\left(\frac{5^y}{y^5}\right)'=\frac{5^y\ln5}{y^5}-\frac{5\cdot 5^y}{y^6}=\frac{5^y(y\ln5-5)}{y^6}$, which gives $y_{min}=\frac{5}{\ln5}$ and $\frac{5^y}{y^5}\geq\frac{5^{\frac{5}{\ln5}}}{\left(\frac{5}{\ln5}\right)^5}=\left(\frac{5^{\frac{1}{\ln5}}\ln5}{5}\right)^5=\left(\frac{e\ln5}{5}\right)^5.$